# Safari 6: window.open() broken in notification onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari6

I'm working on an app that uses Safari 6/Mountain Lion's HTML5 notifications. When the user clicks on the notification, I'd like to open a new window with the relevant URL. This works fine in Chrome (the `window.open()` call doesn't get caught by the pop-up blocker because it's in the notification's `onclick` handler). However, in Safari 6, it looks like it doesn't recognize that the notification `onclick` is a user-initiated event handler, so the call to `window.open()` silently fails and returns `undefined`. Is this a bug? Is there any good workaround?